# Pgbouncer: Multiple Instances on same host receiving same TCP connection when using SO_REUSEPORT

Tags: unix, tcp, database, postgresql, linux-kernel

I was able to setup two `pgbouncer` instances for database connection pooling, on a single VM (CentOS 7.0) listening to same port (6432) on two different TCP socket (I believe) using Linux Kernel feature `SO_REUSEPORT`. From the documentations the kernel is supposed to load-balance between two socket and send the connection to one of socket at a time however in my case in the pgbouncer logs(separate files) I have seen both instances receives the same connection.

I have seen that the TCP connection distribution works based on some hashing which take ip/port combination for routing. Do I need to differentiate incoming connections somehow to achieve the expected behaviour of routing to single socket? For testing I am using a `psql` client from another VM.

**UPDATE**

Even though both receives connection with **login attempt to pgbouncer** only one of them establishing connection with Database. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Both listener socket will be notified that a new connection is available but only one `accept` will succeed in getting it, because there is only one connection. I don't see anything in the documentation which says otherwise. It's not that much different from sharing a single listener socket between multiple processes, only that there are multiple separate listener queues vs. one shared listener queue.

Comment: So you saying the setup working normal? As long as the DB get connection from only one instance it's fine which is I verified and seems okay.

Comment: It works as I would expect it to work.